# Вызов метода производного класса

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Интересует вопрос по производным классам. Есть класс **product** и у него есть 2 подкласса **food**, и **clothing**. У каждого производного класса есть индивидуальный метод (SetCreateDate в food например). Для хранения использую вектор базового класса, но когда понадобилось узнать к какому производного классу принадлежит строка внутри вектора и вызвать из него уникальный метод производного класса - столкнулся с проблемой невозможности вызова. Как я понял, я или неправильно заношу в вектор, или мне нужно хранить данные вне вектора?

Ниже весь код и указание место затруднения, [вот ссылка](http://nephalemcube.ru/lab4.zip) на архив с файлами (проект для CodeBlocks)

**food.h**:

```
#ifndef FOOD_H
#define FOOD_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "product.h"
using namespace std;
class food: public product  {
    public:
        food(string, int, string);
        void show();
        void SetCreateDate(string);
    protected:
    private:
        string CreateDate;
};
#endif // FOOD_H
```

**food.cpp**

```
    #include "food.h"
    food::food(string N, int P, string M) {
        Name=N;
        Volume=P;
        CreateDate=M;
    }
    void food::SetCreateDate(string cat) //индивидуальный метод этого подкласса
{
        CreateDate = cat;
    }
    void food::show() {
        cout << "Имя товара: " << Name << " Цена:" << Volume << "Дата производства: " << CreateDate <<endl;
    }
```

**clothing.h** :

```
#ifndef CLOTHING_H
#define CLOTHING_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "product.h"
using namespace std;
class clothing: public product {
    public:
        clothing(string, int, string);
        void show();
        void SetCSize(string);
    protected:
    private:
        string CSize;
};
```

**clothing.cpp** :

```
#include "clothing.h"
clothing::clothing(string N, int P, string Pr) {
    Name = N;
    Volume = P;
    CSize = Pr;
}

void clothing::SetCSize(string cat) //индивидуальный метод этого подкласса
{
    CSize = cat;
}
void clothing::show() {
    cout << "Имя товара: " << Name << " Цена:" << Volume << "Размер: " << CSize <<endl;
}
```

**product.h** :

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class product
{
    public:
        product();
        ~product();
        virtual void show();
        void SetName(string);
        int GetVolume();
        void SetVolume(int);
        string ReturnType();
    protected:
        int Volume;
        string Name;
    private:
};
#endif // PRODUCT_H
```

**product.cpp** :

```
#include "product.h"
product::product(): Volume(0)
{
    Name="Noname";
}
int product::GetVolume()
{
    return Volume;
}
void product::SetName(string N)
{
    Name=N;
}
void product::SetVolume(int P)
{
    Volume=P;
}
 void product::show()
{
    cout<<"Name: "<<Name<<" Volume: "<<Volume<<endl;
}
product::~product()
{
    //dtor
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "product.h"
#include "food.h"
#include "clothing.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    vector<product> data_arr;


    food row1("Сыр Мацарелла", 229, "Продкуты питания");
    data_arr.push_back(row1);
    food row2("Кофе Якобс", 183, "Продкуты питания");
    data_arr.push_back(row2);
    clothing row3("Джинсы регелар муж.", 1990, "Одежда");
    data_arr.push_back(row3);
    clothing row4("Толстовка Ults.", 1970, "Одежда" );
    data_arr.push_back(row4);

    for (int i = 0; i < data_arr.size(); i++) {
        data_arr[i].show();
    }

    char Key;
    cout << "\n" << "Желаете что-нибудь изменить?(y/n)" <<endl;
    cin >> Key;

    if (Key=='y') {
        recursive_command_row:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < data_arr.size(); i++) {
                data_arr[i].show();
            }
            int command_num;
            string command_row;
            cout << "\n" << "Введите номер строки, в которой хотите сделать изменения" << endl;
            cin >> command_num;
            if(command_num <= data_arr.size()) {
                //вот тут нужно узнать к какому подклассу принадлежит строка и data_arr[command_num] и вызвать уникальный метод
            }
            else {
                goto recursive_command_row;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, что такое [mcve]. Возможно, Вы даже сами решите свою проблему в процессе упрощения кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше сделать в базовом классе виртуальную функцию

```
public:
   virtual void setCreateDate(string) = 0;
```

а в векторе хранить не объекты, а указатели на них. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class D1 : public B
{
public:
    D1() {}
    ~D1() {}
    void f() { cout << "I'm a D1" << endl; }
};

class D2 : public B
{
public:
    D2() {}
    ~D2() {}
    void f() { cout << "I'm a D2" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<B*> v;
    v.push_back(new D1);
    v.push_back(new D2);
    v[0]->f();
    v[1]->f();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
I'm a D1
I'm a D2
```

Comment: В 2016 году использовать голые указатели на объекты - пример очень плохого кода. Это крайне не рекомендуется. Гораздо логичнее использовать умные указатели, разумеется.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ваш вектор хранит объекты базового типа, соответственно базовый тип не знает о методах, которые есть у наследников. Либо нужно в базовый тип добавить абстрактный метод и его реализовать у наследников, либо проверять тип, чтото вроде такого

```
food* f = dynamic_cast<food*>(&(data_arr[i]));
if (f != NULL)
  f->SetCreateDate("1/1/2001");
```

но это мягко говоря не совсем красивое решение

Comment: Да вы что, при `push_back` объекта *производного* класса в вектор объектов *базового* класса он просто обрезается и никакой `dynamic_cast` уже не поможет. Хранить нужно указатели.

Comment: @Harry: `dynamic_cast`, разумеется, никакой проблемы здесь не решает и решить не может в принципе.  Если в векторе хранятся объекты типа `product`, то никакой `dynamic_cast` их в `food` превратить никогда не сможет. Такой `dynamic_cast` будет всегда гарантированно возвращать null-указатель.

Comment: Также стоит заметить, что никакое "добавление абстрактного метода" здесь не поможет тоже. Добавление абстрактного (pure?) метода в `product` приведет только к тому, что `vector<product>` перестанет компилироваться вообще. В любом случае, полиморфизм тут никак не поможет: `vector<product>` может содержать только объекты типа `product` и никакого другого. Никакой полиморфизм в таком векторе невозможен. Как уже было правильно замечено, полиморфизм в таких контейнерах возможен только в том случае, если контейнер хранит указатели/ссылки на объекты, а не сами объекты.